# Is there a standard organized palette of colors according to shade?

Tags: c#, colors

I want to populate a list of colors with 30 or so general colors, but I want the list to have related colors grouped together so the user can find them easily.

I feel like someone ought to have a general list of ordered colors where similar colors are situated together, but I can't seem to find such a list.

Comment: If you ordered them by hex code wouldn't they be in "shade order"?

Comment: [Color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space) is generally represented as being 3- (or occasionally 4-) dimensional. I don't see how you can simply put them in a 1-dimensional list without having some very close visual neighbors ending up very far away from each other on the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such predefined list of *similar colors*. But you can try to create one based on Hue (see [HSV/HSL color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)) from `KnownColor` enumeration:

```
var listOfColors =
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))
        .OfType<KnownColor>()
        .Select(kc => Color.FromKnownColor(kc))
        .OrderBy(c => c.GetHue());
```